# Как удалить заданные символы в строке

Tags: javascript

Всем добра!
Есть строка такого вида: 
**return showWiki({w: 'wall290708618_2192'}, false, event);**

Как сделать так что бы осталось только: **wall290708618_2192**

код должен быть на javascript. Буду рад если поможете

Comment: Уточните где новая строка должна отобразиться.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = "return showWiki({w: 'wall290708618_2192'}, false, event);";
let output = /'(.*)'/.exec(input)[1];
console.log(output);
```